# Update a value on each document with a value existing on that document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

**Objective**:
I would like to update each document's *points_left* with the document's *max_points* value.

**Player.js** (Schema)

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let PlayerSchema = new Schema({
    player_id: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    points_left: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    max_points: {
        type: Number,
        default: 5
    },
    created_date:{
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    },
});

let Player = mongoose.model("players", PlayerSchema);

export default Player;
```

**cron.js** (cron job that plays every 24 hours)

```js
/** This is not actually updating **/
Player.updateMany(
    {},
    [{"$set": { points_left: "$max_points" }}]
)
```

The below query works on MongoDB via terminal.

```
db.players.update(
    {},
    [{"$set": {points_left: "$max_points"}}], 
    { multi : true }
)
```

**Expected**: `{player_id: 1, points_left: 5, max_points: 5, created_date: 1234567890}`
**Actual**: `{player_id: 1, points_left: 0, max_points: 5, created_date: 1234567890}`

Comment: Your update is valid. Are you using ```await```? ```await Player.updateMany(```

Answer (score 0):

If your using an async function make sure you are using await before calling updateMany

```
await Player.updateMany(
    {},
    [{"$set": { points_left: "$max_points" }}]
);
```

If not execute the query or it will not run, `.then()` will also execute if you need a callback.

```
Player.updateMany(
    {},
    [{"$set": { points_left: "$max_points" }}]
).exec();
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a work-around. This one cycles through all of the documents and saves the points_left to max_points

````js
Player.find({})
        .then( docs => {
            docs.forEach(doc => {
                doc.points_left = doc.max_points
                doc.save();
            })
        });
    ```
````

Comment: This is far from efficient and will break when your players collection gets to big. If updateMany is still not working please post more code to debug, since there is something else afoot. You can consider ```cursor.next()``` if you plan to continue to loop but ```updateMany``` is the best solution.